# Extracting Overlapping Parts of Single Polygon Layer using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing, buffer, overlapping-features, openjump

I have a single polygon layer with over 200 buffers with a lot of overlapping areas. I want to use QGIS to create a new layer representing the overlap. I've seen several questions that are similar, but haven't been able to figure it out yet. I'm new to QGIS, so I may be overlooking a simple solution.

I'd like to save out the red overlap from this example:

[image]

From this question:
[Remove overlapping buffers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89483/remove-overlapping-buffers)

Similar to this question, but I'm using QGIS 2.8.1
[how to extract overlap from non-dissolved buffer zones in qgis 1.7.4](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26386/how-to-extract-overlap-from-non-dissolved-buffer-zones-in-qgis-1-7-4)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately I do not know how to do it with QGIS but here is how to do the job with another open source GIS OpenJUMP.

Source data

[image: source layer]

Take the Polygon overlay tool

[image: Polygon overlay in the menu]

Dialogue asks to give Layer A and Layer B as inputs. Use the same layer for both. OpenJUMP will show an error message but don't care about that because it is still creating the intersections. Parts which were common for two or more polygons will have NaN value in all the attributes which can be used for filtering.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Dialogue** asks to give Layer A and Layer B as inputs. Use the same layer for both. OpenJUMP will show an error message but don't care about that because it is still creating the intersections. Parts which were common for two or more polygons will have NaN value in all the attributes which can be used for filtering.

Comment: This is just a copy past of a part of user30184s answer.